# Displaying PDF File In Javafx Using PDFJS Library In Webview

Tags: javascript, javafx, pdf-viewer

PDFJS PDF viewer working fine if the pdf file size less then 64KB; if the file size is more then 64KB which showing no display. Please help me to resolve the issue.

**Here is my code:**

```
byte[] data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(PDFFILE));
String base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data);
engine.executeScript("openFileFromBase64('" + base64 + "')");
```

**Java Version:**

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)
```

[image: PDFJS]

Comment: Why do you want to display your PDF via WebView? Is that your use case?

Comment: Is there any other way to view my pdf file on the JavaFX AnchorPane?  Please help me.

Comment: Either a high-performance solution here https://github.com/mipastgt/JFXToolsAndDemos#awtimage or a more complete PDF viewer here https://github.com/dlsc-software-consulting-gmbh/GemsFX#pdfview